# MySQL SELECT * WHERE column='value' from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, join

Edit2:

I like to get all values from **2 tables** WHERE the value of **highlight='1'**
highligh is a column present in both tables. Both tables have an unique structure.

I want to get all data from both tables where highlight='1'

```
 SELECT * FROM painting, instaview WHERE highlight='1'
```

...both give me the following error:
**"Column 'highlight' in where clause is ambiguous"**

I searched a lot and found a lot about this error but only complicated JOIN causes that are different than my case. i know the column is in both tables but I want the results of those 2 table queries joined.

Edit1:
As requested the structure of both tables:

```
Column    Type  Comment
id        int(6) Auto Increment 
category  varchar(3)    
filename  varchar(30)   
title     varchar(200)  
material  varchar(200)  
year      varchar(4)    
highlight tinyint(1)
active    tinyint(1)
```

Comment: Qualify the column names that exist in both tables.

Comment: If a column name appears in more than one table in a query, you have to qualify them with the table name or an alias like `painting.highlight` and `instaview.highlight` or with the respective aliases. Other than that your question is unclear. [Edit] it and provide a [example], i.e. the schema as `CREATE TABLE` statements, sample data as `INSERT` statements and the desired result with that sample data a tabular text. Do not use screenshots or any other images for that.

Comment: I see my question is very minus-fised. I'm new to mySQL. I did not need to use JOIN but I needed UNION. Problem solved now.

Answer (score 2):

You need to say from which table, you are querying the highlight.

Can you try like this ?

```
SELECT * FROM painting JOIN instaview ON painting.highlight='1'
```

Comment: This joined all results of both tables. What I wanted is only the rows of each 2 tables WHERE highlight='1'. I did not know about the 'qualify' column names as I'm very new to MySQL. But I found the missing part: UNION !

Answer (score 1):

I did not know about the "qualify", but this joined my data in more columns, I just wanted the results of both tables. After more searching I found the keyword: UNION

```
SELECT * FROM painting WHERE highlight=1 
UNION
SELECT * FROM instaview WHERE highlight=1
```

This did the trick! 
*(I like to excuse myself for not being very clear in my question, for me this was all very new)*

Answer (score 0):

If you want `highlight='1'` in both tables, and don't want to specify a table, you may use

```
SELECT * 
FROM painting 
JOIN instaview USING (highlight)
WHERE highlight='1'
```

The fields used in USING are "combined", and tablename qualification not needed.

PS. This is "bad practice" - specify tablenames for all fields when there are more than one table in whole query source (even when some fieldname is unique over data source - it is present in one table only).